# How to get current global IPv6-prefix as a variable in python

Tags: python, ipv6

how can I get my current global IPv6 prefix in python?

Let's say I have the global IP `2010:a:b:c::400/64`  on  `eth0`, how can I get this address in python?
And is there a way to split the prefix?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [netifaces](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/netifaces) to do that:

```
>>> import netifaces
>>> addrs=netifaces.ifaddresses('ens3')
>>> addrs[netifaces.AF_INET6]
[{'netmask': 'ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff::/64', 'addr': '2001:19f0:4400:4983:5400:ff:fe54:1677'}, {'netmask': 'ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff::/64', 'addr': 'fe80::5400:ff:fe5e:1977%ens3'}]
```

note that there is a link-local ipv6 address which starts with `fe80`.

Answer (score 0):

For such process you can try `check_output` in `subprocess` module of python .
A simple example for same:

```
from subprocess import check_output
output=check_output(['ifconfig'],shell=True).decode('utf-8')
print(output)
```

This will print the output of `ifconfig` . Hope it helps , happy coding!

Comment: This assumes that `ifconfig` is installed, which it may not be on modern Linux systems. It also assumes that the system is Linux, which it may not be.

Comment: Even if it is installed, `ip` is the modern answer.